# C incompatible pointer error

Tags: c, pointers

I need help resolving this issue. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person{
    char *name[100];
    char *nationality[100];
};

void put_values(struct Person *p, const char *name){
  strncpy(p->name, name, 500);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct Person *person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    put_values(person, argv[1]);
    free(person);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
ex17t.c: In function ‘put_values’:
ex17t.c:19:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strncpy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from ex17t.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:131:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of   type ‘char **’
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `char *name[100]` is appropriate for a person with over 90 names.  You mean `char name[100]`. If you go for 200 nationalities, you can have true 'citizens of the world'; there are only about 180 nationalities, I believe.

Comment: Why is the third argument of `strncpy` `500`? Where did `500` came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, name means an array of 100 char pointers.
But for strncpy, the first argument is a pointer of char.
so you should do like this:

```
struct Person{
    char name[100];
    char nationality[100];
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Your structure should be (without the `*` characters):

```
struct Person {
    char name[100];
    char nationality[100];
};
```

The way you had it, `name` is actually an array of 100 character *pointers* rather then 100 characters. Unless your name is `Juan Romirez Sancho Ricardo Agusti Donatello Alfonso ... Ramundo Ronaldo Bus Stop F’tang-F’tang Ole Biscuit Barrell` and you want to be able to process each name independently, that's probably not what you're after.

It's also probably not wise to limit your `strncpy` to 500 characters when the field you're trying to copy in to has only 100 :-)

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the declaration of `Person`:

```
struct Person{
    char name[100];
    char nationality[100];
};
```

Your declaration suggests a person with 100 possible names and 100 possible nationalities, which must be dynamically allocated. This is not the intended use of `Person`: it appears that you wanted a single name / nationality, with 99 characters + the null terminator each.

Answer (score 1):

By defining

```
struct Person{
    char *name[100];
    char *nationality[100];
};
```

You have a pointer to an array of chars.  Since an array of chars is equivalent to a pointer to a bunch of chars, `char *name[100]` is the equivalent to a pointer to a bunch of pointers to a bunch of chars.  That might be useful if you intended to have multiple groups of 100 char arrays, but it is clear that this wasn't your intention.

```
strncpy(p->name, name, 500);
```

Under the above definition would be trying to copy the string into a pointer that points to a bunch of chars, instead of the desired

```
struct Person{
    char name[100];
    char nationality[100];
};

strncpy(p->name, name, 500);
```

which copies the string into a bunch of chars.